# Update a single feature in WIX 3.11 installer while leaving the other ones unchanged

Tags: wix

I've been looking for a solution for this but no luck anywhere, so I'm asking here.

I have a WIX 3.11 MSI installer that installs my app. My app has multiple features - the app (.NET Core WPF), the database (PostgreSQL 12), the documentation (PDF). When there are updates, 99% of the time it's just updates in the app. But if the user reinstalls all features on every update, the loose data since the database gets deleted and created again.

**Is there a way to only affect selected features on minor/major upgrades**, or am I getting this upgrading wrong altogether?

Here's how my Product.wxs looks like (I've removed variables and replaced GUID's):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" Name="$(var.AppDisplayName) $(var.bitness)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" Version="$(var.Version)" Language="1033">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" />

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <Condition Message="!(loc.YouNeedToBeAdmin)">
      Privileged
    </Condition>

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="$(var.CabName)" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.NewerVersionAlreadyInstalled)" 
                  AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="Complete" Title="!(loc.FeatureComplete)" Level="1" Description="!(loc.FeatureComplete)" Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" TypicalDefault="install" Absent="disallow">
      <!--MAIN APP FEATURE-->
      <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="!(loc.FeatureMainApplication)" Level="1" Description="!(loc.FeatureMainApplication)" TypicalDefault="install"  AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" Absent="disallow">
        <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
        <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="MainApplicationComponents" />
      </Feature>

      <!--DATABASE FILES FEATURE-->
      <Feature Id="Database" Title="!(loc.FeatureDatabase)" Level="1" Description="!(loc.FeatureDatabase)" TypicalDefault="install"  AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" Absent="allow">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="PostgreModule" />
      </Feature>

      <!--DOCUMENTATION FEATURE-->
      <Feature Id="Documentation" Title="!(loc.FeatureDocumentation)" Level="1" Description="!(loc.FeatureDocumentation)" TypicalDefault="install"  AllowAdvertise="no" InstallDefault="local" Absent="allow">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Documentation" />
      </Feature>

    </Feature>

    <!--PostgreSQL Custom Actions calling bat files-->
    <CustomAction Id="PostgreSQLCreator"
      FileKey="createPostgreSQL.bat" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

    <CustomAction Id="PostgreSQLDestroyer"
      FileKey="deletePostgreSQL.bat" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="PostgreSQLCreator" After="InstallFiles">
        <![CDATA[(&Database=3) AND NOT(!Database=3)]]>
      </Custom>
      <Custom Action="PostgreSQLDestroyer" Before="RemoveFiles">
        <![CDATA[(&Database=2) AND (!Database=3)]]>
      </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    </Product>

  <!--CREATING DIRECTORIES-->
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="PlatformProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.AppFolderName)">
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.AppDisplayName)"/>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramDataFolder" Name="$(var.AppFolderName)">
          <Directory Id="ApplicationDatabaseFolder" Name="PostgreSQL" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <!--MAIN APP EXE-->
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MainApplicationComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="AdremWpf" Guid="SOME-GUID-HERE" >
        <File Source="$(var.AppSingleExePath)" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <!--MANUAL PDF-->
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Documentation" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ReferenceManual" Guid="SOME-GUID-HERE">
        <File Id='Manual' Name='Manual.pdf' Source='Manual.pdf' KeyPath='yes'>
          <Shortcut Id='StartmenuManual' Directory='DesktopFolder' Name='My Manual' Advertise='yes' />
        </File>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <!--SHORTCUTS-->
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="SOME-GUID-HERE">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="$(var.AppDisplayName)" Description="!(loc.AppDescription)" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.AppSingleExeName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.AppFolderName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="SOME-GUID-HERE">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Name="$(var.AppDisplayName)" Description="!(loc.AppDescription)" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.AppSingleExeName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.AppFolderName)" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have figured a way to do this. WIX has a thing called Boostrapper project, which is able to take multiple setup projects (msi or exe files) and install them all within a single installer. After playing with it a little bit, I've noticed that if you deploy a new version of the boostrapper installer that has some new versions of sub-installers and some same versiones of sub-installer, only the new ones get reinstalled.

Example:

Imagine you have two versions of the bootstrapper installer that have these sub-installer versions:

Boostrapper Installer 1.0.0.0

- WPF app installer 1.0.0.0
- Database installer 1.0.0.0

Boostrapper Installer 1.0.1.0

- WPF app installer 1.0.1.0
- Database installer 1.0.0.0

If you install bootstrapper installer 1.0.0.0 and then the bootsrapper installer 1.0.1.0 only the WPF app gets reinstalled, leaving the database untouched.